# show results on typing in textbox mvc view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to use a type of Intellisense for text box where if a user enters particular character in the text box it will auto display results below the text box as suggestion. I had done this previously in asp.net but wanted to do this using MVC 4 now.I am using it in MVC 4 along with jquery mobile. I have a text box with me now. what steps do i need to proceed to get the results in the text box.

```
 @Html.TextBox("name", null, new { id = "SearchBox", @class = "SearchBox" })
```

wanted to use the show suggested results concept for this text box in MVC view. Thanks.

Comment: use JQuery Autocomplete

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor also has a nice tutorial on how to implement an intellisense like feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`jQuery UI autocomplete`](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) plugin. Basically you will need to set a controller action that will be invoked with AJAX and it will be passed as parameter the `term` that the user entered in the textbox. This controller action should return as JSON result the list of suggestions that the plugin will display.

For example:

```
public ActionResult Suggest(string term)
{
    // TODO: use the term here to query your data source
    // and return the suggested results as JSON:
    var results = new[]
    {
        new { id = "1", label = "label 1", value = "value 1" },
        new { id = "2", label = "label 2", value = "value 2" },
        new { id = "3", label = "label 3", value = "value 3" },
    };
    return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and on the client attach the plugin to the textbox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#SearchBox').autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("Suggest")',
            minLength: 3,
            select: function (evt, ui) {

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, i will use it out. Will mark as answer once i have implemented it out.

Comment: its working bro, thanks. i had only added <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: the code is not working after post back bro. i can find similiar problem all over net but no correct solution. i use this code in layout in order to work everywhere.